# json response angular2 not able to get the key

Tags: json, angular

i have got below data in response, i need to reach at error key. Could anyone guide me how to reach there and show it on UI in form of error.

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"location":"body","param":"email","msg":"Email cannot be empty"},{"location":"body","param":"email","msg":"Email is not valid"}]}}
```

thanks in advance

```
 if (loginModel.username && loginModel.password) {
      this.loginService.login(loginModel).subscribe((resp) => {
        this.loginService.authStorage.setAuthorizationHeader(resp['success']);
        if (resp['success']) {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
        }
        this.invalidUsernamePassword = true;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(resp['error']));
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

i have used this angular code.

Comment: Please let us see your Angular code and what have you tried until now

Comment: @M98 code added

Answer (score 0):

```
data = { "error": { "errors": [{ "location": "body", "param": "email", "msg": "Email cannot be empty" }, { "location": "body", "param": "email", "msg": "Email is not valid" }] } };
```

If the response is in `data` property then you can access through

```
this.data.error.errors.forEach(error => {
  console.log(error.msg);
});
```